# JavaScript won't display date using HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using a JavaScript function called showDate() that is passed a parameter (called id). I am trying to get the function to display the date with the innerHTML property that is passed to the function in the function call.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My bored html</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function showDate(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>
</head>
<p id = "Datepara" style = "font-family:comic sans ms;color:orange;text-align:center;font-size:25px;">
Date: 24/9/12 <br /><br /><br/>
</p>
<input type = "button" onclick = "showDate(Datepara)" value = "Display today's date" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
showDate(Datepara)
```

by

```
showDate('Datepara')
```

Otherwise you're passing the html element and not just the id.

Comment: Dammit! I knew it was something really trivial xD

Answer (score 2):

You need to quotes around the element's id string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My bored html</title> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
function showDate(id) 
{ 
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = Date(); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<p id = "Datepara" style = "font-family:comic sans ms;color:orange;text-align:center;font-size:25px;"> 
Date: 24/9/12 <br /><br /><br/> 
</p> 
<input type = "button" onclick = "showDate('Datepara')" value = "Display today's date" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Firebug and Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature help me a lot.

Comment: Have 2 use internet explorer >:( I have chrome at home

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is:

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "show Date('Datepara')" value = "Display today's date" />
```

I hope this is helpful.